# Source for outgoing connection in nethogs

Tags: networking, malware

I see several outgoing connections in `nethogs` (please see screenshot below), where my server is connected e.g. via its port 445 (samba?) to someone else.
However, `ss` does not show any process running/listening on port 445 and samba is not even installed. Some thing for port 993, I don't have postfix/dovecot or something like this running. What could be the source of these connections?

P.S.:
I used to check via `ss -tulpne | grep 445` for example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using tcpdump in order to see which kind of traffic is being sent? Maybe that traffic capture will help you; as the captures in "real" time are quite difficult to undestand I would recommend to save the dump in a file to check it later.

`tcpdump -i interface_name -n -s 0 -w /tmp/capture.cap`

You let it capturing for a couple of seconds and later you press `CTRL + C`. Then you can check the capture using Wireshark, check that I think that may be very informative.